# IntelliJ creating Integration Testing Environment

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm creating another source set for integration testing, but every time my gradle rebuilds it turns my main test root folder back to source root folder (blue), when I want it to be test root folder (green). What do I need to configure in my build.gradle so that this is fixed?

```
sourceSets {
    integration {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
}

dependencies {
    intTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

[image]

Everytime I manually change it to testsources root and rebuild it just turns back to blue.

I followed this documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `intTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation`? It should be like in the documentation: `intTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation`.

Comment: If you scroll further down the page you will see that if I use testImplementation it should take the dependencies from my other test package I believe. I originally had it as just implementation.

Comment: Check out the [`kordmap`](https://aalmiray.github.io/kordamp-gradle-plugins/) plugins; more specifically the [`integration-test`](https://aalmiray.github.io/kordamp-gradle-plugins/#_org_kordamp_gradle_integrationtest) plugin which already does what you are trying to do, including configuring intellij

Comment: @smac89 awesome thanks man

Comment: Why do you need to manually set the test or source roots? IDE does it automatically. The fact the it marks it as test source or a production source should not matter for the end result. IDE sets the project structure according to the Gradle configuration.

Comment: @Andrey because I already have a main and test package now I want to do a integration package but it wont mark it as test so I'm unable to run it

Comment: If it is marked as a production sources (instead of tests) you will also be able to run it. IDE should mark it as a source directory automatically after Gradle refresh.